# account.rb:17:in `withdraw': undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodErro r)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, operator-keyword

I am getting error while executing form terminal.

```
withdraw : undefined method '-'
```

I do not understand why. I have tried editing with sublime and notepad++.

```
class Account
    def initialize(name, balance, phone_no)
        @name = name
        @balance = balance
        @phone_no = phone_no
    end

    def deposit(amount)
        @amount += amount
    end

    def withdraw(amount)
        @amount -= amount
    end

    def display()
        puts "Name: " + @name
        puts "Phone number: " + @phone_no.to_s
        puts "Balance: " + @balance.to_s
    end

    def transfer(amount, target_account)
        @balance -= amount
        target_account.deposit(amount)
    end

    def status
        return @balance
    end
end
```

Comment: Where is account object you are operating on?

Comment: Plus, you have not initialized `@account` anywhere in the class above. You have `@balance`, `@phone_number` etc, but `@account` is always `nil`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't these two methods operate on `@balance`?

```
def deposit(amount)
    @balance += amount
end

def withdraw(amount)
    @balance -= amount
end
```

`@amount` is `nil`. You're doing so

```
@amount = nil - amount
```

and `nil` doesn't have a `-` method

Answer (score 0):

`@amount` is `nil` in your `deposit` and `withdraw` methods. And you can't call the `-` method on a `nil` object. Probably you misspelled `@balance` as `@amount`?

```
def deposit(amount)
  @balance += amount
end

def withdraw(amount)
  @balance -= amount
end
```